# Como fazer para plotar um gráfico em python usando um arquivo contendo arrays numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, gráfico

Boa tarde! estou criando um programa em python que plota o gráfico da função quadrática (y=x**2), no entanto, precisa colocar os dados de x e de y em um arquivo e plotar o gráfico extraindo os dados desse arquivo, mas não estou conseguindo fazer isso. Ficarei grato pela ajuda, pois sou iniciante na linguagem e não sei de muitas funcionalidade. Segue o que eu conseguir fazer até então:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

start = float(input('valor inicial: '))
stop = float(input('valor final: '))

x = np.arange(start, stop+1) 

y = x**2

arq = open('dados.dat','w')
arq.write(str(x))
arq.write(str(y))
arq.close()

plt.plot()
plt.show()
```

Comment: Os dados do array precisam ser gravados no formato texto? Se for possível gravar em formato binário, você pode salvar diretamente com o método np.save: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.save.html#numpy.save

Comment: Acredito que sim. Se for possível, nesse caso, como eu plotaria o gráfico?

Comment: Você quer ler um arquivo e depois plotar o x e o y? Se sim, manda um exemplo desse arquivo

Comment: Caso sua ideia não seja salvar no arquivo, apenas substitua o plot `plt.plot(x, y)`

Comment: quero ler o arquivo e depois plotar o gráfico

o arquivo foica dessa forma:
[-10.  -9.  -8.  -7.  -6.  -5.  -4.  -3.  -2.  -1.   0.   1.   2.   3.
   4.   5.   6.   7.   8.   9.  10.][100.  81.  64.  49.  36.  25.  16.   9.   4.   1.   0.   1.   4.   9.
  16.  25.  36.  49.  64.  81. 100.]

(usei um exemplo que vai de -10 até 10, da [ até onde tem "][" eh o x, dps disso eh o y )

Answer (score 1):

#### Para gravar os dados no arquivo:

```
import numpy as np

start = float(input('valor inicial: '))
stop = float(input('valor final: '))

x = np.arange(start, stop+1) 

y = x**2

np.savetxt('dados.dat', [x, y], delimiter=",")
```

#### Para ler os dados do arquivo e plotar:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x, y = np.loadtxt('dados.dat', delimiter = ",")

plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Muito obrigado ! :)